# Cut marks on pothos leaves

Tags: houseplants

I have a golden pothos house plant and I have noticed certain cut marks on the leaves. What's the underlying cause? Is it due to a pest or some bacterial infection?

[image: cut marks on the pothos leaf]

Answer (score 1):

I have this too. What I notice is that they only appear where leaves are folded against something, be that another [stronger] leaf, part of the vine or a nearby surface. It doesn't happen during the summer, only during winter when it's cold and there's is little sun light; I guess when the plant is at its weakest.